# Make apache load all servlets in Tomcat's webapps folder

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I am running Apache2.2 and Tomcat7.0 on Windows.

How do I setup JkMount to allow access to any deployed webapp on Tomcat in the form domain.com/tomcat/nameOfWebapp?

Here is my workers.properties:

```
# Define 1 real worker using ajp13
worker.list=worker1
# Set properties for worker1 (ajp13)
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009
```

Here is the relevant part of my httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
<IfModule jk_module>

    JkWorkersFile D:/servers/tomcat7.0/conf/workers.properties
    JkLogFile D:/servers/tomcat7.0/logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogStampFormat "[%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S] "
    JkRequestLogFormat "%w %V %T"
    JkLogLevel info
    JkOptions +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories

    Alias /tomcat "D:/servers/tomcat7.0/webapps/"

    <Directory "D:/servers/tomcat7.0/webapps/">
        AllowOverride None
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Location /*/WEB-INF/*>
        deny from all
    </Location>

    JkMount /tomcat/* worker1
</IfModule>
```

If I just do something like JkMount /manager* worker1 I can get the manager webapp to work, but how can I get it to load any app that is deployed to Tomcat?

What I have now gives me this error:

```
The requested resource (/tomcat/manager/) is not available.
```

when trying to visit domain.com/tomcat/manager.
The error is given by Tomcat so it's getting to it but for some reason it doesn't want to load it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything to be available under, say, /tomcat/[webappname], then you can do it like this:

```
JkMount /tomcat/* worker1
```

Then, re-name all your web applications' WAR files to use nested-paths that all fall under /tomcat, like this:

```
CATALINA_BASE/webapps$ mv ROOT.war tomcat.war
CATALINA_BASE/webapps$ mv app1.war tomcat#app1.war
CATALINA_BASE/webapps$ mv app2.war tomcat#app3.war
CATALINA_BASE/webapps$ mv app3.war tomcat#app3.war
```

The effect will be that now, all webapps will have /tomcat/app1 (or whatever) as their context path. If you're written them correctly, this relocation should not be a problem at all, and you can allow httpd to continue to serve requests (even to *.jsp if you want) to paths outside of /tomcat/*.

Comment: That seemed to work, though I didn't have the wars, I just named the foloders with the hashtag. Why does the hashtag cause this behavior? I haven't seen that in the documentation related to JkMount but I may have missed it.

Comment: @Talon876 That's not a mod_jk thing, it's a Tomcat thing: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Naming

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I wanted to have this in my httpd.conf:

```
JkMount /*.jsp worker1
JkMount /*/tomcat/ worker1
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like that just gets me permission errors.